# Repeatedly ask for existing file

Tags: python, file-handling

> Write a function named ask_file_name that repeatedly prompts the user for a file name until the user types the name of a file that exists on the system. Once you get a good file name, return that filename as a String.

this is what I have done till now:

```
import os.path
def ask_file_name():
    file = input("Type a file name: ")
    x = os.path.exists(file)
    if x :
        return file
    else:
        ask_file_name()
```

but it is giving the following error:
expected string, but no value was returned

Comment: After you add the missing return, you should consider rewriting this code to use an iterative solution (a while loop) rather than a recursive solution (calling ask_file_name() from within ask_file_name()).

Comment: Refer this post for other ways to repeat input until valid https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use a while loop.

```
def ask_file_name():
    file = input("Type a file name: ")
    while not os.path.exists(file):
        file = input("Type a file name: ")
    else:
        return file
```

Please note recursion is an option, however max recursion depth can be an obstacle.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
def ask_file_name():
    file = input("Type a file name: ")
    x = os.path.exists(file)
    if x :
        return file
    else:
        return ask_file_name()
```

Comment: Recursion is an option but you must be aware of maximum depth.